# why moveBy and moveTo not working in my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I think it is an easy questions but I am new in JavaScript

Why buttons "but3" and "but4" not working when I try moveBy or moveTo a new window?

thanks

HTML code

```
<input type="button" value="New window" id="but1" onclick="createwin()" />
<input type="button" value="close window" id="but2" onclick="closewin()" />
<input type="button" value="moveby window" id="but3" onclick="movebywin()" />
<input type="button" value="moveto window" id="but4" onclick="movetowin()" />
```

javascript code

```
var win1;

function createwin(){
    win1 = window.open('http://www.google.com','google','width=500,height=500');
}

function closewin(){
    win1.close();
}

function movebywin(){
   win1.moveBy(100,100);
}

function movetowin(){
  win1.moveTo(100,100);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says

```
Permission denied to access property 'moveBy'
```

To access the properties of another window, it needs to be in the same domain.

Your code works if you replace www.google.com with a file in the same directory.